# Generating a PDF from MySQL data and sending it using Postfix, without using PHP?

Tags: mysql, linux, pdf, postfix-mta

This is probably a beginner question but I'm having difficulties finding general guidelines on how to achieve this. Regarding context, this is an exercice and not meant to run in any sort of production environnement.

I have a MySQL database containing email adresses and item order details. I'd like to generate a simple PDF from the ordered item information (item name, order quantity, total price), then mail it to the intended recipient, using PostFix. PHP is not installed on the server and should very preferably not be installed at all, which apparently makes things harder when it comes to generating the PDF file.

Could you offer some guidance regarding this? Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Making pdf files is a report-generation problem, and must be done with some sort of program. "Some sort of program" requires some sort of programming language.

Of course, fetching data from a MySQL database and generating email messages to send to a mail transfer agent like the Postfix mta also requires a programming language.

Many programming languages support these functions, not just php. You can do them with Java, C#, PERL, C++, and so forth.

If you can't install a programming language (php or another) so you can write the program to get the data, make the pdf, and send it as an attachment to an email message, You Are Out of Luck™.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I do not have access to a programming language (if some bash arcane magic does not count, or maybe even Perl). This is supposed to be a minimal installation of CentOS with only the mysql-server package.